# Что такое "байда"?

Tags: этимология, лексика, значение-слов

О громоздкой вещи в шутку говорят "байда".

А что такое ***байда*** на самом деле?

Comment: С ударением на первый слог так можно сокращать "байдарку".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

БАЙДА, -ы; ж. Разг.-сниж. Трепотня, пустые разговоры; ерунда. Возм. связано с «байда», «байдара», «байдак» -- разновидность речных судов; возм. также сближение с устар. диал. «байдуга» -- беззаботный человек, «байдуже» -- безразлично, невнимательно, ненужно (из укр.). (из Словаря русского арго) Ср.: в польском baj dużo "болтай больше", т. е. "можешь говорить что угодно".

Comment: Это Елистратов? Вот за что его "люблю", так это за совершенно необъянимую этимологию. Ну какие, к черту, тут речные суда? Какая связь?
Не говоря о том, что "суда" эти не речные, а морские - быстроходные лодки, популярные у контрабандистов в Тамани и на Каспии. Отсюда, видимо, байдара, байдарка.

Answer (score 1):

**Байда.**
Это слово встречается в нескольких языках у народов, населяющих земли у Каспия и Черного моря, и носит крайне разнообразный характер.

У тюркских народов оно означает "хозяин", "мастер". У народов Южного Приуралья — пустотелое изделие, сосуд для чего-то, в том числе, лодка, выдолбленная из цельного дерева. Довольно свежее и популярное значение: от легкого алеутского морского судна (байдара-байдарка).

У славянских народов (например, чехов, поляков, украинцев) популярно другое значение байды: рассказчик, говорун, трепач, пустозвон, бездельник. Это значение является непосредственно производным от глагола "баять" (говорить, рассказывать). Близкородственные производные в великорусском наречии: *убаюкивать, кот-баюн, баюшки-баю*. В том смысле, что кот-баюн и есть настоящий байда.

Есть и остро парадоксальные переносы. Например, великорусское "бить баклуши" словари переводят на украинский как "байдикувати". Действительно, и там, и там имеется ввиду "бездельничать", хотя смысл существенно отличается. Производство баклуш для ложек — легкий незамысловатый труд, а вовсе не ведение пустых разговоров...

Comment: И деревяшка, и кот, и человек, чего там ещё... Всё байда.

Answer (score 0):

Байда в старорусском имеет несколько значений. Одно из них — "что-то пустое, полое" — развилось в *ерунду*, в *чепуху*. Отсюда, имхо, *байда* — ерундовина; употребляется аналогично "фиговине".